# JSON Parsing with GSON

Tags: java, android

I have the following Json string.How to parse this kind of Json using Gson in Java?Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
"acclst":[{
        "accountInfoData":[{
                "userId":9,
                "rid":"1-Z5S3",
                "acnme":"acc_1234.",
                "actpe":"Fabricator / Distributor",
                "mph":"2660016354",
                "euse":"Biofuels",
                "com":"0",
                "sta":"Active",
                "stem":"BBUSER5",
                "wsite":"",
                "fax":"",
                "zone":"",
                "crted":"BBUSER4",
                "statusX":1,
                "partyId":0,
                "address":[]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"conlst":[],
"actlst":[],
"prolst":[],
"code":"200"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your Gson getter/Setter class will be

**sample.java**

```
public class sample {

    public String code="";
    ArrayList<String> conlst; 
    ArrayList<String> actlst;
    ArrayList<innerObject> prolst;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getConlst() {
        return conlst;
    }
    public void setConlst(ArrayList<String> conlst) {
        this.conlst = conlst;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getActlst() {
        return actlst;
    }
    public void setActlst(ArrayList<String> actlst) {
        this.actlst = actlst;
    }
    public ArrayList<innerObject> getProlst() {
        return prolst;
    }
    public void setProlst(ArrayList<innerObject> prolst) {
        this.prolst = prolst;
    }

}
```

**innerObject.java**

```
public class innerObject {

    ArrayList<String> accountInfoData;

    public ArrayList<String> getAccountInfoData() {
        return accountInfoData;
    }

    public void setAccountInfoData(ArrayList<String> accountInfoData) {
        this.accountInfoData = accountInfoData;
    }


}
```

**secondInnerObject.java**

```
public class secondInnerObject {

    public String userId="";
    public String rid="";
    public String acme="";
    public String actpe="";
    public String mph="";
    public String euse="";
    public String com="";
    public String sta="";
    public String stem="";
    public String wsite="";
    public String fax="";
    public String zone="";
    public String crted="";
    public String statusX="";
    public String partyId="";
    ArrayList<String> address;
    ArrayList<String> accountInfoData;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getRid() {
        return rid;
    }
    public void setRid(String rid) {
        this.rid = rid;
    }
    public String getAcme() {
        return acme;
    }
    public void setAcme(String acme) {
        this.acme = acme;
    }
    public String getActpe() {
        return actpe;
    }
    public void setActpe(String actpe) {
        this.actpe = actpe;
    }
    public String getMph() {
        return mph;
    }
    public void setMph(String mph) {
        this.mph = mph;
    }
    public String getEuse() {
        return euse;
    }
    public void setEuse(String euse) {
        this.euse = euse;
    }
    public String getCom() {
        return com;
    }
    public void setCom(String com) {
        this.com = com;
    }
    public String getSta() {
        return sta;
    }
    public void setSta(String sta) {
        this.sta = sta;
    }
    public String getStem() {
        return stem;
    }
    public void setStem(String stem) {
        this.stem = stem;
    }
    public String getWsite() {
        return wsite;
    }
    public void setWsite(String wsite) {
        this.wsite = wsite;
    }
    public String getFax() {
        return fax;
    }
    public void setFax(String fax) {
        this.fax = fax;
    }
    public String getZone() {
        return zone;
    }
    public void setZone(String zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }
    public String getCrted() {
        return crted;
    }
    public void setCrted(String crted) {
        this.crted = crted;
    }
    public String getStatusX() {
        return statusX;
    }
    public void setStatusX(String statusX) {
        this.statusX = statusX;
    }
    public String getPartyId() {
        return partyId;
    }
    public void setPartyId(String partyId) {
        this.partyId = partyId;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(ArrayList<String> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getAccountInfoData() {
        return accountInfoData;
    }
    public void setAccountInfoData(ArrayList<String> accountInfoData) {
        this.accountInfoData = accountInfoData;
    }


}
```

to fetch

```
String json= "your_json_string";
Gson gson= new Gson();
sample objSample=gson.fromJson(json,sample.getClass());
```

thats it

Comment: but if i want to get the **acme** of that json.how to fetch in my main class.

Comment: objSample.getacclst.get(0).getaccountInfoData.get(0).getacme().toString();

Comment: I am a complete JSON newb. So, I'm reading his JSON text and then reading your code, and I am confused. I see the very first "array" is acclst in the JSON. But I don't see any reference to it in Sample.java. And then prolst in JSON is empty with nothing to indicate type, yet Sample.java shows "ArrayList<innerObject> prolst". I am guessing this probably ought to be (the missing) acclst instead of prolst, right?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using List<> (interface) as opposed to ArrayList<> (implementation)? Or is that problematic for GSON deserialization?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `JSONObject` to parse this json in android.

Take a look at the following link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 1):

Android already contains the required JSON libraries. You can use a valid string or a file for input. Here is code and explanation taken from [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class JsonParser extends Activity {
    private JSONObject jObject;
    private String jString = "{\"menu\": {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\", \"popup\": { \"menuitem\": [ {\"value\": \"New\",   \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"}, {\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"}, {\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}]}}}";//write your JSON String here

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            parse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void parse() throws Exception {
        jObject = new JSONObject(jString);

        JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");
        String attributeId = menuObject.getString("id");
        System.out.println(attributeId);

        String attributeValue = menuObject.getString("value");
        System.out.println(attributeValue);

        JSONObject popupObject = menuObject.getJSONObject("popup");
        JSONArray menuitemArray = popupObject.getJSONArray("menuitem");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    .getString("value").toString());
            System.out.println(menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                    "onclick").toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-parsing-json-data-with-gson/) you have a tutorial which answers your needs - Android + Gson