# Extract and Save Json to Arraylist Android

Tags: android

How can i extract the json below and save it in an arraylist.

```
   {
            "trains": {
                "train": [
                    {
                        "@id": 1000000103,
                        "@version": 1,
                        "@status": "active",
                        "@name": "dffffff",
                        "@description": "ffffff half of the nineteenth century.",
                        "@city": "fff",
                        "@phone": "+230 595-1454",
                        "@email": "ffffr@mffc.mu",
                        "@website": "www4u",
                        "@latitude": -5.2882,
                        "@longitude": 3.499,
                        "@defaultLocale": "",
                        "@holes": 48,
                        "@par": 72,
                        "@slope": 0,
                        "@distance": 5.005273,
                        "circuits": {
                            "circuit": []
                        },
                        "localizations": {
                            "localization": []
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@id": 1000000105,
                        "@version": 1,
                        "@status": "active",
                        "@name": " xClub",
                        "@description": "",
                        "@city": " xlet",
                        "@phone": "+44465\t",
                        "@email": "",
                        "@website": "wweffl.com",
                        "@latitude": -2.040318,
                        "@longitude": 54548,
                        "@defaultLocale": "",
                        "@holes": 18,
                        "@par": 32,
                        "@slope": 0,
                        "@distance": 2441673,
                        "circuits": {
                            "circuit": []
                        },
                        "localizations": {
                            "localization": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

    }
```

my working

```
try {

                jobj_trouve_train = new JSONObject(reponse_trouve_train);

                String jsonobj = jobj_trouve_golf.getString("trains");
                //String jsonobj1 = jobj_trouve_golf.getString("train");

                //jobj_trouve_train = new JSONObject(reponse_trouve_train);

                //jsonArray = jobj_trouve_golf.getJSONArray("trains");
                //jsonArray= new JSONArray(jsonobj);

                //System.out.println("jsonArray "+jsonArray);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
try {

                jobj_trouve_train = new JSONObject(reponse_trouve_train);

                JSONObject jsonobj = jobj_trouve_train.getJSONObject("trains");
                JSONArray jsonobj1 = jsonobj.getJSONArray("train");

          for(int i = 0;i< jsonobj1.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonj = jsonobj1.getJSONObject(i);

                System.out.println("@id "+jsonj.getString("@id"));
                //   Same for remaining all 
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block                  

                   e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thank you this line      JSONArray jsonobj1 = jsonobj.getJSONArray("train"); was the solution aligato

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Gson` library developed by Google to parse Json into `objects`.
The reference is here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
And, a sample example is here:
[JSON Parsing with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632541/json-parsing-with-gson)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject trains = jobj_trouve_train.getJSONObject("trains");
JSONArray trainArray = trains.getJSONArray("train");

JSONObject train1 = trainArray.getJSONObject(0);
...
```

if i didn't get  confuse maybe this one will be right

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jasonArray = new JSONArray(result.getProperty("trains").toString());
```

for (int i = 0; i < jasonArray.length(); i++) {

```
JSONObject jsonObj = jasonArray.optJSONObject(i);
trainObject = new JSONObject(jsonObj.optString("train").toString());
int id = trainObject.optInt("id");

and so on..
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object void toObject(String jsonMsg) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject trains= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonMsg).nextValue();
    if(trains.has("trains")){
               JSONArray train = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(object.getString("train")).nextValue();
                for (int t = 0; t < jsonArray.length(); t++) {
                   String temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(t).toString();
                   JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(temp).nextValue();
                   if(object.has("@id"))
                      object.getString("@id");
                   // now similar procedure of reading
                   // read values and save it in an "object"
    }       
    return savedObject;
}
```

-- tested, i have tried to modify code to match your JSON data. complete the rest.